# References and typewriter in xdef

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, typewriter

Is there a way to use \texttt{} and references in a xdef?
As example, I have following environment:

```
\NewEnviron{named-environment}{
 \xdef\bodycontent{\BODY}
}
```

Which I want to use in this way:

```
\begin{named-environment}
    This is the \texttt{message}
\end{named-environment}
```

Later, I want to use \bodycontent in an overview table.

It seems that the brackets aren't recognized correctly.

Comment: `\texttt` and most other font changing commands are not expandable and won't really do the right thing in an `\xdef`/`\edef` context. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `\NewEnviron{named-environment}{%
 \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\bodycontent\expandafter{\BODY}%
}` might work.

Comment: Also: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand once `\BODY`:

```
\NewEnviron{named-environment}{%
  \xdef\bodycontent{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}%
}
```

Alternatively

```
\NewEnviron{named-environment}{%
  \toks0=\expandafter{\BODY}%
  \xdef\bodycontent{\the\toks0 }%
}
```

Don't forget to protect the end-of-lines.